# ReactJs custom hook on switch theme

Tags: reactjs

Hello I would like to ask for help with my custom hooks
I can't structure it in a way that I just put my themes in a single file

I need to import my themes in my hook and my component
I've tried everything and I can't solve it, basically I need to save the themes preferences in localstorage and the default theme is light

code:

```
import { darkTheme, lightTheme } from './themes/index';

export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = usePersistedState('theme');
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme.type === 'light' ? darkTheme : lightTheme);
  };
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={toggleTheme}>a</button>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

my hook:

```
function usePersistedState(key) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const storageValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    console.log(storageValue);
    switch (storageValue) {
      case 'dark':
        return darkTheme;
      case 'light':
        return lightTheme;
      default:
        return lightTheme;
    }
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(state.type));
  }, [key, state]);

  return [state, setState];
}
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly? Can you show simple example of what `./themes/index` looks like? Thanks!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-goodall-x7x7d  Here the example, I wanted to make a switch theme saving in localStorage, but in my code I'm having to pass my thema on my component to my hook and return the thema on my hook