# React Hooks and localStorage dont set correct value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I had an idea to make a hook to increase the font size and save preferences in localStorage
basically I have a state that goes from 1 to 4, and then when I click the button add I add +1 to the state until I reach number 4
and on the remove button I remove 1 from the state until 1

But I have doubts on how to save this to my location
basically if i don't use my useState just with getInitialValue It works normally.

**like this gif, If I add the value manually it works:**

[image]

**but if I try to use my setFont I have problems (as it is saved in localStorage):**

[image]

**and i got this on localStorage :**

[image]

**code:**

```
export default function App() {
  const { fontSize, setSize } = useFontSize();
  console.log(fontSize);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setSize(fontSize + 1);
        }}
      >
        add
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setSize(fontSize + 1);
        }}
      >
        remove
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**hook:**

```
export default function useFontSize(defaultSize = { size: 1 }) {
  const [fontSize, _setSize] = useState(getInitialSize);
  function getInitialSize() {
    const savedSize = localStorage.getItem('_size_acessibility_font');
    const parsedSize = JSON.parse(savedSize);
    if (parsedSize) {
      const { size } = parsedSize;
      if (size >= 1 && size <= 4) {
        return size;
      }
    } else {
      return defaultSize.size;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(fontSize, 'on useEffect to set on localStorage');
    localStorage.setItem(
      '_size_acessibility_font',
      JSON.stringify({ size: fontSize }),
    );
  }, [fontSize]);

  return {
    fontSize,
    setSize: ({ setSize, ...size }) => {
      console.log(size, 'on function set size');
      if (size > 4) {
        return _setSize(4);
      }
      if (size < 1) {
        return _setSize(1);
      }
      return _setSize(size);
    },
  };
}
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-newton-x0mqd

I don't know if this is the best logic for this context, if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a tad overengineered and upsets a few hooks idioms. For example, returning a named object pair for a hook is less typical than an array pair. The `set` function itself is complex and returns the result of the `_setSize` calls. Naming could be clearer if `fontSize` matched `setSize` by using `setFontSize`.

`({ setSize, ...size })` is problematic since the caller is (correctly) providing an integer.

Here's a minimal, complete version that fixes these issues (local storage is mocked since Stack Snippets is sandboxed):

```js
const localStorageMock = (() => {
  const storage = {};
  return {
    getItem: k => storage[k],
    setItem: (k, v) => {storage[k] = v.toString();}
  };
})();

const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const useFontSize = (defaultSize=1) => {
  const clamp = (n, lo=1, hi=4) => Math.min(hi, Math.max(n, lo));
  const clean = n => isNaN(n) ? defaultSize : clamp(+n);
  const storageName = "_size_acessibility_font";
  const fromStorage = clean(localStorageMock.getItem(storageName));
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(fromStorage);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorageMock.setItem(storageName, fontSize);
  }, [fontSize]);

  return [fontSize, size => setFontSize(clean(size))];
};

const App = () => {
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useFontSize();
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Font size: {fontSize}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setFontSize(fontSize + 1)}>
        +
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setFontSize(fontSize - 1)}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I was a little confused, did you suggest not using localStorage?

Comment: No, absolutely use `localStorage`. I can't use it on stack snippets because it's sandboxed, so for your actual code, you can change `localStorageMock` to `localStorage` and remove the mock function.

Comment: I found your code very boom and clear

I ended up getting a little lost with my code, I'll try to move to localStorage
if i have difficulty can i comment here?

Comment: Sure. Check out [Writing your own custom hooks](https://blog.bitsrc.io/writing-your-own-custom-hooks-4fbcf77e112e) and [React custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). The authors even hookify localStorage which seems like overkill for this case.

Comment: I thought about localStorage to keep the user's font preference

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, i'm a little confused trying to understand the function clamp

Comment: It's generic: [clamping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)). All it does is constrain the number to the specified `lo..hi` range, inclusive at both ends.

Comment: thanks a lot, u can help me with this question about hooks? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244554/reactjs-custom-hook-on-switch-theme it is a swtich theme, I managed to solve this in a slightly confusing way, but I would be happy to see what your solution would be like.

Answer (score 0):

In `useFontSize`, you return

```js
return {
  fontSize,
  setSize: ({ setSize, ...size }) => {
    console.log(size, 'on function set size');
    if (size > 4) {
      return _setSize(4);
    }
    if (size < 1) {
      return _setSize(1);
    }
    return _setSize(size);
  },
};
```

However, in `App`, you call `setSize` with just a number `setSize(fontSize + 1);` when it is expecting an object.

If you change `useFontSize` to return

```js
return {
  fontSize,
  setSize: (size) => {
    console.log(size, 'on function set size');
    if (size > 4) {
      return _setSize(4);
    }
    if (size < 1) {
      return _setSize(1);
    }
    return _setSize(size);
  },
};
```

It should work.

Note, you will want to clear your current local storage, or add some error checking.

Also note, although it is just an example, both add and remove use `fontSize + 1`